# tricks in keras sequential model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras CNN model and I'm trying to recreate the same model using tensorflow v1 API. But I noticed even though the model structures are the same, their performance are very different, Keras model performance is always better. So I wonder if there is any well known tricks or optimizations enabled by default in Keras Sequential model.

The dataset I used is https://www.kaggle.com/trolukovich/food11-image-dataset.
This is my Keras model and the parameters here are just something arbitrary.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(4, (8, 8), 
          padding='SAME',
          activation='relu', 
          input_shape=(128, 128, 3), 
          kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),  padding='SAME'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (8, 8), 
          activation='relu', 
          padding='SAME', 
          kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='SAME'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(layers.Dense(11, kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And this is the model in tensorflow v1 API

```
def assemble_graph(g):
  with g.as_default():
    # code for input
    image_paths = tfv1.placeholder("string", [None], "image_path")
    labels = tfv1.placeholder("int32", [None], "y")

    image_paths_ts = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_paths, dtype=tf.string)
    labels_ts = tf.one_hot(labels, 11, name="y_onehot", dtype=tf.int32)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths_ts, labels_ts))
    def map_fn(path, label):
      image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))
      image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
      image = tfv1.to_float(image) / 255.0
      return image, label
  
    dataset = dataset.map(map_fn).shuffle(5000).batch(128)
    iter = tfv1.data.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)
    x, y = iter.get_next()

    # model
    weights = {
        'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tfv1.random_normal([8, 8, 3, 4])),
        'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tfv1.random_normal([8, 8, 4, 8])),
        'W_fc': tf.Variable(tfv1.random_normal([32*32*8, 16])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tfv1.random_normal([16, 11]))
    }

    biases = { 
        'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tfv1.zeros([4])),
        'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tfv1.zeros([8])),
        'b_fc': tf.Variable(tfv1.zeros([16])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tfv1.zeros([11])) #for the output neurons
    }
    layer1 = maxpool2d(tfv1.nn.relu(conv2d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1']), 2)
    layer2 = maxpool2d(tfv1.nn.relu(conv2d(layer1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2']), 2)
    layer2_flat = tf.reshape(layer2, [-1, 32*32*8])
    layer3 = tfv1.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer2_flat, weights['W_fc'])+biases['b_fc'])
    logits = tf.matmul(layer3, weights['out'])+biases['out']

    cross_entropy = tfv1.reduce_mean(tfv1.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits))
    optimizer = tfv1.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)

    return optimizer, cross_entropy
```

One issue I found with my tfv1 implementation was that logit numbers are huge in the first a couple of iteration, which caused big loss numbers. After I applies batch norm the issue got fixed. But I didn't see big loss numbers in the Keras implementation, so this made my wonder if there is any hidden tricks that Keras Sequential model used.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the difference might be in the optimizer. (Different optimizer implementation, and different learning rate). Did you check the logits "before" training? That's important.

Comment: I tried to use "tf.keras.optimizers.Adam" in my tfv1 implementation. But I'm still seeing the big logits issue. For "logits before training", are you referring to the logtis in the first step of training before updating any weights?

Comment: even before. Before starting training. But it works if you can do it as you said.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that, the logits are huge and I was able to fix it with batch norm. But not sure why keras sequential model doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Weird... Maybe the weight initializers.... You could check the distribution of the weights of a layer